# Can't edit textbox with onfocus after postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a mask on several textboxes using onblur and onfocus.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ContactNameTextBox" runat="server"
    onblur="if(value=='')value=defaultValue;" 
    onfocus="if(value==defaultValue)value='';"></asp:TextBox>
```

I set the value in code behind like the following. I use an if statement as I want to change back to the mask on postback if someone where to enter a string of spaces in the field

```
if (ContactNameTextBox.Text.Trim() == "")
{
    ContactNameTextBox.Text = "Contact Name";
}
```

This is all working correctly. If changes are made to this textbox, such as a name is entered, you can click in the textbox and just edit as per normal. My issue is that I have some controls on my page that perform a postback. Once that occurs, then clicking in any textbox, regardless if the mask or another value, it clears the box as if it was a mask. What do I need to do so that only the value of "Contact Name" in this case, acts as a mask on postback, but any other value performs as per normal so that the user can edit or delete the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just needed a break. I got the solution.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="ContactNameTextBox" runat="server"
    onblur="if(value==' ')value=defaultValue;" 
    onfocus="if(value=='Contact Name')value='';"></asp:TextBox>
```